# Time Validation with Jquery (Give alert when under the time)

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form in html.

```
<input type="text" name="time">
```

User must fill the time form with 00:08:12 or above that. 
If user type under that, like 00:08:10 , alert will appear.

Could you please show me how to do this with Jquery?
Thanks before

Comment: And could you please show us whatever you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

What about call to setTimeout in the moment you want the counter to start.

```
setTimeout(alert('...'), timeInMs);
```

Being timeInMs = 492000 (8:12 mins)

This code will show an alert at that time. If you want a validation just put a flag on the setTimeout and if the flag is true show the alert...